# overloadded method on a class template, compiler doesn't see it, see only other overloaded function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm somehow new to templates and I'm trying to modify some library that provide matrix and vector operation to c++, i have a vector class which I'm trying to overload the operator() for it to handle an operation like this Vector(2:5) will return a vector that has elements 2,3,4,5 of the original vector, and I'm using a class called colon where colon(2:5) will represent the (2:5) effect as i found that c++ has no operator: .
hope i gave a proper introduction.
The relevant code is as follows

The Vector Class

```
template< size_t M, typename T = float >
class Vector
{
public:
typedef T   value_type;
inline T& operator()( size_t index );
inline const T& operator()( size_t index ) const;
template <size_t N> Vector<N,T> operator()(const  colon &cex) const;
.
.
}
```

and the corresponding implementation

```
template< size_t M, typename T >
template< size_t N>
Vector<N,T>
Vector<M,T>::operator()( const colon &cex ) const
{
long i, ii, st = 0, in = 0, en = 0, s;
cex.apply(M, st, in, en, s);
if (s && (st>0) && (st>M))
{
Vector<N,T> result;
for (i=st,ii=0;i+=in,ii++;i<=en,ii<N)
{
result(ii)=array(i);
return result;
}

}
return 0;
}
```

the return 0 here is just a place holder, it should return an empty vector.
the colon class (which is taken from another library and modified by me).

```
class colon
{
public:
/// Colon expression '(:)'
colon() { _flag = 'a'; }
/// Colon expression of type '(2:5)'
colon(long s, long e) { _s = s; _i = 1; _e = e; _flag = 'r'; }
void apply(long s, long &f, long &i, long &l, long &n) const;

private:
/// Type of colon expression.
char _flag;
/// First index.
long _s;
/// Increment.
long _i;
/// Last index.
long _e;

}; /* class colon */
```

and the relevant implementation is

```
void
colon::apply(long n, long &st, long &in, long &en,
     long &le) const
{
switch (_flag)
{
    case 'r':
        if ((_i == 0 ) || ((_e - _s) / _i < 0 )) le = 0;
        else
        {
            st = _s;
            in = _i;
            en = _e - (_e - _s) % _i;
            le = (_e - _s) / _i + 1;
        }
        break;
    case 'a':
        if (n)
        {
            st = 1;
            in = 1;
            en = n;
            le = n;
        }
        else le = 0;
        break;

 }
}
```

The code used to test the functionality is

```
bool ok = true;

Vector< 4, double > v;
double data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

v.iter_set( data, data+4 );//just puts elements of data inside v with the same type

// test  Vector colon
{
    bool ok = true;
    Vector<3,long> test;
    test=v(colon(2,4));//Problem

}
```

The error now is

```
C2664: 'const double &Vector<M,T>::operator ()(size_t) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'colon' to 'size_t'
```

output of compiler is

```
error C2664: 'const double &Vector<M,T>::operator ()(size_t) const' : 
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'colon' to 'size_t'
with
[
M=4,
T=double
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, 
or the operator cannot be called
```

???? help is appreciated

Comment: As we told you in comments on your other question, the `size_t N` *will never be deduced*. This kicks your operator out of consideration.

Comment: Oh dear, what's wrong with declaring `operator()` to take two indices instead of this `colon` hack?

Comment: @Xeo : Sorry , but i don't understand, and really sorry if this is wasting your time, but i don't know what you mean by size_t N will never be deduced, what should i do to fix it? i thought that removing the T and putting only size_t N is the way to fix it.

Comment: Okay, question: How do you expect your `operator()` to decide the value of `N`? :)

Comment: @jork i'm using colon because there is more than two numbers as input to this function, it my be (:) or (2:1:5) or (end:3). I'm not really good at this and still learning.

Comment: @Xeo , actually i thought it will be inside the function, but you are right, it should know from the declaration, but how i can define a function like this then, i tried to use only Vector as a return type but as it is a template class, it requires to put the return typ in Vector < , > format?

Comment: You can't easily. The `colon` takes run-time data for delimiting and striding, but the `Vector` need compile-time data. You could opt for making `colon` a class template like `template<int B, int E, int S = 1> struct colon` and have the arguments passed as template arguments.

Comment: @Xeo , ok then if i had the function take input (colon(2,4), N) for example, would this work? but again i will have the problem of defining N inside the declaration and implementation, right? or there is a workaround for that?

Comment: ok i have changed the overloading part to use a regular function with following arrangement

    `template< size_t M, typename T >`
    `template< size_t N >`
    `inline Vector< N, T >`
    `Vector< M, T >::get_sub_Vector(colon& cex)`

and when i use the function i use it like that

    `Vector< 3, double > v3 = v.get_sub_Vector<3>(colon(2,4));`

and it is working now, without deducing N in the declaration. don't know if this is the right way. just wanted to share maybe someone is new like me and have this problem, thanks to everyone who tried to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have too much to say to fit it into a comment, so I will use the answer for this (although it does not answer your question directly):

You need to know what your use cases will be.
If you are going to do much with runtime variables, then there is no sense in implementing it all in templates. If you want to use templates only, then you need to do so too with `class colon`. I will give you some hints to both.

First let me explain your problem in more detail than what the comments could say.

Lets see few use cases assuming we have a `Vector<5, int> vec;`.

Case "compile-time size":

```
//get the entries with indices 1 to 3 (including)
Vector<3, int> vec2 = vec(colon(1, 3));
```

For this code everything is known at compile time so it would be possible to do this at compile time (though it is unnecessary ugly for this purpose).

Case "run-time size":

```
//we get the variables a and b as input from the user at runtime
Vector<?, int> vec2 = vec(colon(a, b));
```

See those `a` and `b` variables? Do you know what values they hold, when you write the program? No you cannot because the user should input them. They could be `0:0` or `0:4` or `42:1337`, who knows what the user will enter (accidentally). When you do not know the value of `a` and `b` you also do not know what will stand at `?`, but you will have to know at compile-time, because every template argument has to be known at compile-time.

Now you need to know what you want to do. Do you want to work with `a:b` (run-time parameters) or do you only ever want to enter constants like `1:3` (compile-time parameters). Depending on this you need to choose, how to implement `Vector<n,T>::operator()`.

You see: As soon as the size of the `Vector` depends on run-time values it cannot be determined at compile-time and it is therefore not possible to return the right sized vector.

You could however implement a compile-time-sized and a run-time-sized vector and colon class to enable both at the cost of a more complex implementation. They would give following pattern:

```
CompileTimeVector CompileTimeVector::operator()(CompileTimeColon);
RunTimeVector CompileTimeVector::operator()(RunTimeColon);
RunTimeVector RunTimeVector::operator()(CompileTimeColon);
RunTimeVector RunTimeVector::operator()(RunTimeColon);
```

This pattern would be necessary for any operation to interoperate between the run-time and compile-time types of Vector and colon.

Comment: Thanks @Nobody for your explanation, now it is much clear to me the difference. this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <size_t N> Vector<N,T> operator()(const  colon &cex) const;
```

is itself templated on N and the value of N isn't deducible from colon, so it isn't considered in the overload set.